# initialize an input tag as tags-input behaves strange

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-tags-input

html:

```
<input type='text'id='some_id' class='form-control', data-role='tagsinput' />
```

js:

```
$("input").tagsinput();
```

but it changes style of input tasg as `display='none'` and adds an extra div.

Here is returned html:

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> <input type="text" placeholder="" size="1"></div>
<input class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" id="some_id" style="display: none;" type="text">
```

[image]

[image]

Why it is behaving strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not strange behaviour and it is functioning correctly. When you do `$("input").tagsinput();`, the library takes that `input`, wraps it in some other markup that it has styles for, and adds the special behaviour you want (which is tagging). This is a common phenomenon in JavaScript libraries.

Comment: You can look at the rendered html and classes and write custom CSS targeting those elements, thereby styling it. Would you mind accepting the answer if it answered your question?